# Is possible to make Jquery Dialog responsive?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to make Jquery UI Dialog responsive? I want that the size of my Dialog is calculated automatically in relation with the size of the screen and the content of the Dialog box. How is possible to realize this?
THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, 'dialogClass' is a way to override jQuery UI Dialog's CSS.

However, some issues can occur because jQuery UI Dialog utilizes inline CSS to achieve placement, width, etc. The fallout from this is that you have to use '!importants' scattered through your CSS to achieve responsive behavior. I was running into this same issue, so I authored [jQuery UI Dialog Extended](https://github.com/jasonday/jQuery-UI-Dialog-extended).

This plugin provides additional functionality to jQuery UI Dialog, including responsive behaviors (height responsive as well).

Answer (score 1):

The dialog widget uses the [jQuery UI CSS framework](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/)  to style its look and feel. If dialog specific styling is needed, the following CSS class names can be used:

- `ui-dialog`: The outer container of the dialog.

  - `ui-dialog-titlebar`: The title bar containing the dialog's title and close button.

    - `ui-dialog-title`: The container around the textual title of the dialog.
    - `ui-dialog-titlebar-close`: The dialog's close button.

    `ui-dialog-content`: The container around the dialog's content. This is also the element the widget was instantiated with.

    `ui-dialog-buttonpane`: The pane that contains the dialog's buttons. This will only be present if the `buttons` option is set.

    - `ui-dialog-buttonset`: The container around the buttons themselves.

Additionally, when the `modal` option is set, an element with a `ui-widget-overlay` class name is appended to the `<body>`.

Other than this you can use **[dialogClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)**

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  dialogClass: "responsive_class"
});
```

The specified class name(s) will be added to the dialog, for additional theming.